# Why is the Wi-Fi in Ubuntu 21.04 so painfully slow?

Tags: ubuntu, wifi

I had been using Ubuntu 21.04 for a while, and all of a sudden the wifi is slow (download rate is not more than ~7000 B/s). *My internet is pretty fast and gives around 50Mbps.*

A few days back, I got myself with ransomware on Windows. I had to reset Windows. After resetting Windows, Ubuntu started to behave sluggishly. I reinstalled Ubuntu 21.04 **twice** using a bootable stick. The safe boot in Windows seems to block my wifi adapter, so I disabled it. Then I had the issue rising again yesterday and today. I disabled the power management, but the issue is still there.. I can't even do an update!

My laptop runs Ubuntu on Dual boot alongside Windows 10.

[Laptop Details](https://www.amazon.in/Dell-Inspiron-5501-15-6-Laptop/dp/B08GY7YLY7)

output of `iplink`

```
1: lo: <LOOPBACK,UP,LOWER_UP> mtu 65536 qdisc noqueue state UNKNOWN mode DEFAULT group default qlen 1000
    link/loopback 00:00:00:00:00:00 brd 00:00:00:00:00:00
2: wlp2s0: <BROADCAST,MULTICAST,UP,LOWER_UP> mtu 1500 qdisc noqueue state UP mode DORMANT group default qlen 1000
    link/ether 5c:3a:45:12:ad:7f brd ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff


$ lshw -c network
  *-network                 
       description: Wireless interface
       product: QCA6174 802.11ac Wireless Network Adapter
       vendor: Qualcomm Atheros
       physical id: 0
       bus info: pci@0000:02:00.0
       logical name: wlp2s0
       version: 32
       serial: 5c:3a:45:12:ad:7f
       width: 64 bits
       clock: 33MHz
       capabilities: bus_master cap_list ethernet physical wireless
       configuration: broadcast=yes driver=ath10k_pci driverversion=5.11.0-16-generic firmware=WLAN.RM.4.4.1-00157-QCARMSWPZ-1 ip=192.168.1.9 latency=0 link=yes multicast=yes wireless=IEEE 802.11
       resources: irq:139 memory:93000000-931fffff

$ iwconfig
lo        no wireless extensions.

wlp2s0    IEEE 802.11  ESSID:"Home (2)"  
          Mode:Managed  Frequency:2.462 GHz  Access Point: 14:A7:2B:62:3B:DE   
          Bit Rate=144.4 Mb/s   Tx-Power=20 dBm   
          Retry short limit:7   RTS thr:off   Fragment thr:off
          Power Management:off
          Link Quality=70/70  Signal level=-37 dBm  
          Rx invalid nwid:0  Rx invalid crypt:0  Rx invalid frag:0
          Tx excessive retries:0  Invalid misc:5   Missed beacon:0

$ speedtest-cli

Testing download speed................................................................................
Download: 0.42 Mbit/s
Testing upload speed......................................................................................................
Upload: 5.75 Mbit/s
```

**Does anyone have any suggestions on how I can make Wi-Fi in Ubuntu 21.04 faster?**

Comment: Check your WiFi `MTU`, using `ip link`. It should be 1492, not 1500.

Comment: @waltinator: why is that? I have 1500 and everything is fine.

Comment: @waltinator, Maybe if he were using DSL, but it's likely that he's not since he gets 50mbps down, so It doesn't need to be 1492 unless the router has somehow changed it's MTU, which is also not likely since his windows seems to work fine.

Comment: @Arjun K Shibu, to be clear, are you using Ubuntu on the same laptop that Windows is on? It is possible that you could have some malware running on the network that is eating all your bandwidth. More info is needed, please admire useful information.

Comment: @Shōgun8 I've given information which I thought would be sufficient, If you need more information, please suggest the kind of information that is required.I  use my laptop for classes and stuff. Ubuntu seems faster than windows and I've been using it from 10.04. This issue has never occured before and the chances of malware eating all my bandwidth is applicable to windows too, right?( I don't know I guess) Windows gives me the peak speed of my network. Whereas Ubuntu gives slow network speed and yes Ubuntu is on the same laptop.

Comment: @@Arjun K Shibu, I did suggest the kind of information. It's difficult for an outsider to guess what your exact setup is, and we are only tryin to help. Why don't you tell us whether it's a dual boot laptop, or if you're running Ubuntu INSIDE of Windows, or whatever it is that you have going on over there.

Comment: It's possible that your boot sector was infected. Perhaps you should test for that. You can find helpful information here. https://security.stackexchange.com/questions/189818/how-to-remove-mbr-rootkits-bootkits.         Other thing to try: installing a different version of Ubuntu, trying a different speedtest server, and rebooting your router.

Comment: @Shōgun8 I did that I installed Ubuntu 20.04 LTS and it was the same so I switched back to 21.04

Comment: Perhaps it's your encryption algorithm: does it happen to be using TKIP?

Comment: I don't know, How to check that?

Comment: Here is how to force it to use AES: ```sudo ifdown wlan0 && iwpriv wlan0 set EncrypType=AES``` Also make sure to set your wifi router to use AES

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In my Wi-Fi I had to change its bandwidth from 20/40 Mhz to 40 Mhz. It fixed the issue everytime I encountered it(speed used to go down some times)

Answer (score -2):

Check your WiFi `MTU`, using

```
ip link
```

also notice your WiFi interface's name.

The `MTU` (Maximum Transmission Unit) is the size of the largest packet that can be sent in a single network transmission. If a packet exceeds the  `MTU` of a link, the data must be split into multiple packets (fragmented). These multiple packets must be sent over the link, received, acknowledged, and reassembled at the far end. If your link is misconfigured, and you have to fragment every packet you send, your actual data transfer rate drops.

Ethernet (wired)  networks use an `MTU` of 1500 bytes.

Due to additional per packet overhead for WiFi (8 bytes PPPoE header), WiFi uses an `MTU` of 1492.

Your `MTU` should be set by your DHCP server, check your router's config.

You can set your own `MTU` (setting does not persist over restarts) with

```
sudo ip link set dev name mtu 1492
```

where "name" is the interface name from above.

Here's an example:

```
walt@squid:~(0)$ ip link
1: lo: <LOOPBACK,UP,LOWER_UP> mtu 65536 qdisc noqueue state UNKNOWN mode DEFAULT group default qlen 1000
    link/loopback 00:00:00:00:00:00 brd 00:00:00:00:00:00
2: enp63s0: <NO-CARRIER,BROADCAST,MULTICAST,UP> mtu 1500 qdisc mq state DOWN mode DEFAULT group default qlen 1000
    link/ether 00:24:21:7f:e5:1c brd ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff
3: wlxf46d04b1790f: <NO-CARRIER,BROADCAST,MULTICAST,UP> mtu 1500 qdisc mq state DOWN mode DORMANT group default qlen 1000
    link/ether f4:6d:04:b1:79:0f brd ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff
walt@squid:~(0)$   sudo ip link set dev wlxf46d04b1790f mtu 1492
[sudo] password for walt: 
walt@squid:~(0)$ ip link
1: lo: <LOOPBACK,UP,LOWER_UP> mtu 65536 qdisc noqueue state UNKNOWN mode DEFAULT group default qlen 1000
    link/loopback 00:00:00:00:00:00 brd 00:00:00:00:00:00
2: enp63s0: <NO-CARRIER,BROADCAST,MULTICAST,UP> mtu 1500 qdisc mq state DOWN mode DEFAULT group default qlen 1000
    link/ether 00:24:21:7f:e5:1c brd ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff
3: wlxf46d04b1790f: <BROADCAST,MULTICAST,UP,LOWER_UP> mtu 1492 qdisc mq state UP mode DORMANT group default qlen 1000
    link/ether f4:6d:04:b1:79:0f brd ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff
```

My WiFi "interface name" is "`wlxf46d04b1790f`".

Comment: this did not help for me :( and I have the same issue.